# Python Beautiful Soup .content Property

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

What does BeautifulSoup's .content do? I am working through [crummy.com's](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html) tutorial and I don't really understand what .content does. I have looked at the forums and I have not seen any answers.  Looking at the code below....

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re



doc = ['<html><head><title>Page title</title></head>',
       '<body><p id="firstpara" align="center">This is paragraph <b>one</b>.',
        '<p id="secondpara" align="blah">This is paragraph <b>two</b>.',
        '</html>']

soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(doc))
print soup.contents[0].contents[0].contents[0].contents[0].name
```

I would expect the last line of the code to print out 'body' instead of...

```
  File "pe_ratio.py", line 29, in <module>
    print soup.contents[0].contents[0].contents[0].contents[0].name
  File "C:\Python27\lib\BeautifulSoup.py", line 473, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError, "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, attr)
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Is .content only concerned with html, head and title? If, so why is that?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: The reason I suspect that the code above doesn't work is because .content is concerned with html, title, and head initially, but not body because it is in a different class in the html hierarchy. Later in the tutorial crummy uses the code below to print body which makes me suspect that body is a in a different hierarchical structure.

    head.nextSibling.name 

If anybody else stumbles upon this post, it is important to read up on html structure. 

Check out [http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.1][1]


  [1]: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just gives you whats *inside* the tag. Let me demonstrate with an example:

```
html_doc = """
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>

<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>

<p class="story">...</p>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
head = soup.head

print head.contents
```

The above code gives me a list,`[<title>The Dormouse's story</title>]`, because thats *inside* the `head` tag. So calling `[0]` would give you the first item in the list.

The reason you get an error is because `soup.contents[0].contents[0].contents[0].contents[0]` returns something with no further tags (therefore no attributes). It returns `Page Title` from your code, because the first `contents[0]` gives you the HTML tag, the second one, gives you the `head` tag. The third one leads to the `title` tag, and the fourth one gives you the actual content. So, when you call a `name` on it, it has no tags to give you.

If you want the body printed, you can do the following:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(doc))
print soup.body
```

If you want `body` using `contents` only, then use the following:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(doc))
print soup.contents[0].contents[1].name
```

You will not get it using `[0]` as the index, because `body` is the second element after `head`.