# Retrieving contents of a CSS Selector

Tags: regex, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract "1381912680" from the following code:

```
[<abbr class="timestamp" data-utime="1381912680"></abbr>]
```

Using Python 2.7, this is what I currently have in my code to get to that stage:

```
s = soup.find_all("abbr", { "class" : "timestamp" })
        print s
```

Should I use regex or can BS do it on its own?

**EDIT**

I tried to using regex but with no luck:

```
import re

regex = 'data-utime=\"(\d+)\"'
x = re.compile(regex)
x2 = re.findall(x, s)
print x2
```

I got: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: RegEx seems fine if you know that all `<abbr>` will be childless. If that is the case, use `data-utime=\"(\d+)\"` to allow for swapped attributes.

Comment: I think this thread may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602398/python-beautiful-soup-content-property

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I tried to apply regex but no luck could you please have a look at the edited qn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below regex to extract the number within double quotes,

```
(?<=data-utime=\")[^\"]*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hX6xA9/1)

Python code would be,

```
>>> import re
>>> str = '[<abbr class="timestamp" data-utime="1381912680"></abbr>]'
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?<=data-utime=\")[^\"]*', str)
>>> m
['1381912680']
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=data-utime=\")` Regex engine sets a marker just after to the string `data-utime="`
- `[^\"]*` Matches nay character zero or more times upto the literal `"`

Answer (score 2):

Python reserves class so you use the format:

```
s= soup.find("abbr", class_="timestamp")
```

but... `<abbr>` is empty so use the above answers :)